# How can I make my cloud app wait idle with minimal cost?

Tags: cron, cloud

I have a light python script that must be launched twice a day: one time at a fixed time and the other at a time determined by the first run.

I would like to host it on the cloud (PythonAnywhere, Google App Engine or AWS lambda…).

The first execution is easy to schedule with crontab-like services they offer.
However, for the second, I found no other way than waiting idle (with `time.sleep` or a python scheduler).

I would like to:

- wait/sleep for free
- dynamically schedule a new one-time task
- make a request to an API that would call my API back at a given time

Answer (score 0):

In AWS this can be accomplished using a state machine. The state machine will allow you to invoke a lambda function. The you can have the state machine wait for an extended period of time (up to one year I think) without execution cost. Then it will invoke the next lambda function.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connectors-lambda.html